# HTTP Error 404 with xampp even though it's connected successfully

Tags: xampp, localhost, http-status-code-404

I've been having a lot of issues with xampp lately. I use it to run wordpress locally, for practice.

I made a new wordpress site last night and it worked fine but after restaring my laptop it stopped.

I changed httpd.conf to listen on 8080, by changing these:

---

Listen 12.34.56.78:8080

Listen 8080

ServerName localhost:8080

---

Apache and mySQL connected successfully:

[image: xampp]

Here is what I get in my browser:

[image: 404 error]

Nothing has been changed with the site since last night, when it worked, or the htdocs folder.

I don't know what else to do :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try like this `http://localhost/` and do you have folder inside `htdocs`

Answer (score 0):

Try with localhost:8080/something

Comment: I have, I should have specified that.

Comment: [Tomcat]  Problem detected!
[Tomcat]  Port 8080 in use by "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"!
[Tomcat]  Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
[Tomcat]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
[Tomcat]  or reconfigure Tomcat and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

I know this is not the error log, but it might help.